# Highlight row with jQuery on checkbox select

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple rows. Each row has a check button. How do i highlight the row (apply style I suppose) when the checkbox is selected?

Comment: Please try to give it a shot first and then come back with some code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
```

See [`toggleClass(`)](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)

Comment: Looks like they both add the class.  Typo?

Comment: @Kerin - it was. I revised my answer, made it more concise using `.toggleClass`.

Comment: Right on.  Incidentally, you just taught me about .closest() - golly, me and jQuery are getting married someday.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":checkbox:checked").each( 
function() 
{ 
    if (this.checked) 
    {
        this.addclass("yourClass");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(":checkbox").click(function(){

       var thischeck = $(this);
       var approved = (thischeck.is(':checked')) ? '1' : '0';
       if(approved) {
           //apply what ever you want
       }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I would try this, not sure if it is an elegant solution.