# Text overflow in table with variable size

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I was looking to implement the following design to the HTML/CSS.

[image]

I have got problems with the text overflow in the column. Currently the table column width is given in the percentage format so that the column width will change depending on the screen size, but there is a minimum width too. In the first text column, you can see that the content is extending and produced a second line due to the long size. How to avoid this problem using the text overflow? Or any other solution? Also, you can see that a set of icons are appearing in the same row when the mouse hover takes place. At this time, the text below the icons should hide and it should be shortened as shown in the design. Can you advise me to get a solution to this problem? I have tried `text-overflow: ellipsis`. But I'm getting problem when the screen width changes. Since I don't have a minimum width due to the variable column width, how to cut short the text in this field? Also in the hover case ??

Please let me know if you want to know anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the text to split in multiple rows, add `white-space:nowrap` rule.
Then, set a `max-width` for the cell.

For the icons, `position` them in `absolute` to the right, with a `z-index` higher then the text. You'll have to add a `relative` position to the containing cell also.
To keep them visible over text, i've added a background color (and some left padding).

---

**EDIT: Fix for Mozilla**

Mozilla seems to ignore `position:relative;` for td elements.
To fix it, you've to wrap the td contents inside another div, and apply this style

```
.tables td {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 200px; /* just an example */
}

.tables td > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}

.linkFunctions {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #FFF9DC;
    padding-left: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 120px; /* just an example */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What if, we need to add some three dont's (...) whenever we cut short the text?

Comment: Add this to .linkFunctions `width: 100%;
max-width: 120px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;`

Comment: But the three dots are not displaying!

Comment: I just realized that you can remove `text-overflow: ellipsis;` from `.tables td` rules

Comment: Yet, the three dots are not displaying!

Comment: :) please add this code to **.linkName** (my bad) `width: 100%; max-width: 120px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;`

Comment: I see.
There's an issue with `position:relative` for the `td` element. You've to wrap the content of `td` into another `div`, this way:
`<td><div style="position:relative;"><a href="" class="linkName">Google siteeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</a>
                            <div class="linkFunctions">
                             ....
                            </div>
                       </div></td>`

Comment: Also, is there any option to make the background highlighted when we check the checkbox of that particular row?

Comment: I edited my answer with Mozilla fix ;) sure you can highlight the row on check, but you need jQuery... Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516568/highlight-row-with-jquery-on-checkbox-select

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you want (regarding the elipsis) but comes very close.

For the `<a>` inside the `<td>` add

```css
td a{
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

(You might need to add a class to them to more easily target them and not ALL `<a>` inside `<td>`s).

And regarding the hover. Float the `div.linkFunctions` right, add the yellow background to it and it will look like it cuts the text accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

All of those require a width to be set, which doesn't make tables fluid as they are intended to be.  Use this: http://jsfiddle.net/maruxa1j/

That allows you to automatically set widths on `<td>` as percentages and the `:after` automatically sizes the overflowed `<span>`